# Javascript: get element's current "onclick" contents

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a page with the following code:

```
<a id="test" href="someurl" onclick="somefunction">link</a>
```

I need to actually read the 'onclick' data. As such, I would like something to the effect of

```
alert(document.getElementById('test').onClick)
```

Sadly, it returns `undefined`. What do I need to do to get `somefunction`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming the tag is well-formed, a tag's attribute can be obtained via [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).

```
document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('onclick')
// -> "somefunction"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick.toString()
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Accessing the `onclick` property of an element will simply return a reference to the function attached to the click event handler, not "onclick data," as the OP requested. Please consider removing as it is wholly incorrect.

Comment: @royhowie Actually royhowie, if there is only one function attached, and you convert it to a string, the function text is there.

Comment: @royhowie I'm really grateful he didn't delete this answer (what a petty thing to suggest) because the accepted top answer does not work in iOS WebKit JSQuery but this one does, saved me a whole night of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript on anchor tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function testClick(id)
  {
     alert(id);
  }

</script>

<a href="#" id="test" onclick="testclick(this.id);">Click</a>
```

Comment: this isn't really anything to do with the question... I'm trying to access what is already IN the anchor tag, i.e. in your example, what could I write that would return "testclick(this.id)"

Comment: Please consider removing this answer as it has nothing to do with the question asked.