# JavaScript get a button's click event raw textual value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a button's `onclick` event raw textual value. For example, if JQuery I could write    `$(this).attr('onclick')` would return me the `onclick` `function`. However, what I want is this as a raw textual value, not as a returned `function`.

Using event to look at a button when it is clicked I see a lot of properties, but none of which look to me what I am looking for. So, I was wondering whether anyone has any experience of obtaining the raw textual value of a click event

Comment: What is "raw textual value"?  Are you looking for the button value, as in `.val()`?  Or `.html()`?

Comment: No, it means what I am asking for. If a button has an event called click, and I do var myevent = $(this).attr('onclick'), I will get back that function as a function. I don't want the actual function itself, I just want its textual value

Comment: You want to execute the function and get the return value from the function called by the onclick event?

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('test').getAttribute('onclick')
```

from this answer: [Javascript: get element's current "onclick" contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253770/javascript-get-elements-current-onclick-contents)

EDIT: (we should not assume that there is an element in the document with the `id` of `test`, but should rather use what we have, namely `this`):

```
this.getAttribute('onclick')
```

Comment: This does work for me in JS as this.getAttribute('click'). It returns null. Because my HTML is a JSF and the tag ids are generated dynamically. What would be the Jquery implementation of this?

Comment: @Andy5, I have edited the answer to help you. Try it with this.getAttribute('onclick')

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind, take a look at the question where the op has a code example. I have edited your answer to relate to that code and will edit the question of the op as well.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind, sure, as your answer was already pretty good as an idea, so it was definitely worth some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr('onclick') + ""
```

will yield the result you want. In more general terms, if you have a `function` and you want to see it textually, just add an empty string to it. Example:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("bar");
}

console.log(foo + "");
```

Comment: This returned null

Comment: @Andy, what did you execute, exactly?