# Execute Javascript Event Directly from PowerShell

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I am navigating to a webpage in Internet Explorer.  I would like to automate the clicking of a link on this webpage.  I am currently looping through all HTML elements with a tag of 'a' on the page until I find the one with the title I am looking for - at which point I .click() it:

```
$links = $ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Foreach($link in $links )
{
    #look for this field by value
    $link.title
    if($link.title -eq "Link I would like to click"){
        Write-Host $link.click()
    }
}
```

The link I'm looking for does not have an ID, so document.getElementById() is not an option.  This particular link has an onclick event defined as:

```
onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'pageLoadStart();','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'navPanelForm\'),{\'navPanelForm:j_idt689:j_idt689\':\'navPanelForm:j_idt689:j_idt689\'},\'\')');return false"
```

Is there any way I can execute this directly without having to loop through ALL the links?

Answer (score 0):

Check if element you need have any distinct features that you can search for - [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), if it doesn't have such, best bet would be to check it's ancestors - div element that hold all links or something like that and search through its children - [`element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) or [`element.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes). If you are searching for specific onclick content [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253770/javascript-get-elements-current-onclick-contents) could help (`element.getAttribute('onclick')`).