# Is it possible to access the onSubmit attribute of HTML tag via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have the following form:

```
<form id="myForm" onSubmit="myFunction()">
   ...
</form>
```

Can I access the value of `onSubmit` from JavaScript? Something like `document.forms.myForm.onSubmit`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: get element's current "onclick" contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253770/javascript-get-elements-current-onclick-contents)

Answer (score 2):

Since `onSubmit` is an attribute you may use `getAttribute` property and thus fetch the value of the attribute.

There you go:

```js
alert(document.forms["myForm"].getAttribute("onSubmit"))
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onSubmit="myFunction()">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
document.forms.myForm.onsubmit.toString()
```

which will return a wrapper function that contains the code in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible please refer the below code,

```
document.forms["formName"].onsubmit = function(){
    // process.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery function attr() function (this function can get any attributes from a selected element for example: onSubmit)

```
$("#myForm").attr('onSubmit')
```